# beta and gamma helping solve an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I want to   compute the following integral:
$$I= \int_0 ^1 e^x\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[4]{1-x^4}} dx$$

I am looking for a clever trick that will give a concrete result for this integral, without much fuss or complicated calculations.

How may I compute that definite integral in an elementary way?

Find a *****closed formula***** containing just elementary functions for this integral or if it *does not exist* I would be curious about a proof that shows it *cannot be expressed* in this way.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\frac{\pi\,_0F_3\left(;\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{1}{256}\right)}{16\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(15\,_0F_3\left(;\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{256}\right)+\sqrt{2}\,_0F_3\left(;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{9}{4};\frac{1}{256}\right)\right)}{480\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{1}{3}\,_1F_4\left(1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{1}{256}\right)$, where $F$ is the hypergeometric function. This can be determined by substituting the Maclaurin series of $e^x$. Not a nice answer…

Comment: Note that this is a follow-up question to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4415759

Answer (score 3):

Trying with $x=\sqrt{\sin (t)}$

$$I= \int_0 ^1 e^x\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[4]{1-x^4}}\, dx=\frac 12 \int_0 ^{\frac \pi 2} e^{\sqrt{\sin (t)}} \sqrt{\sin (t) \cos (t)}\, dt$$
$$I=\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {n!}\,\int_0 ^{\frac \pi 2}  \sin ^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(t)\,\cos^{\frac 12} (t)\,dt$$ The antiderivative is known in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function :
$$\int \sin ^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(t)\,\cos^{\frac 12} (t)\,dt=-\frac{2}{3} \cos ^{\frac{3}{2}}(t) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1-n}{4};\frac{7}{4};\cos ^2(t)\right)$$
$$J_n=\int_0 ^{\frac \pi 2}  \sin ^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(t)\,\cos^{\frac 12} (t)\,dt=\frac{2 }{3}\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+6}{4}\right)}$$  So
$$I=\frac{1 }{3}\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+6}{4}\right)\,\Gamma(n+1)}$$

If
$$a_n=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+6}{4}\right)\,\Gamma(n+1)}\quad\implies\quad \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac 1 n \Bigg[1-\frac{7}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \Bigg]$$ and the summation should converge quite fast.

Wolfram Alpha gives the [awful result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BGamma%5B%283+%2B+n%29%2F4%5D%2F%28Gamma%5B1+%2B+n%5D*Gamma%5B%286+%2B+n%29%2F4%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D) in terms of hypergeometric functions as @LCandleEater already commented. But we do not need many terms; computing the partial sums
$$S_p= \sum_{n=0}^p \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+6}{4}\right)\,\Gamma(n+1)}$$
$$S_{12}=\color{red}{3.089258529}253$$ while the infinite summation gives
$\color{red}{3.089258529315}$ (difference $=6.23 \times 10^{-11}$)

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. I would like a more concrete result without using the convergence of this complicated series.

Comment: @shangq_tou The result is as concrete as you are likely to get, considering how **non**-elementary the integral is. It is not reasonable to expect a nicer form